# The number of Hall $\pi$-subgroups of a $\pi$-separable group - Alexandre Turull article

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, p-groups, frattini-subgroup

This is an article which Alexandre Turull wrote. Lemma 2.1. states

**Lemma 2.1.** *Suppose $H$ is a finite group, acting on the finite group $F$, and assume that $|H|$ and $|F|$ are relatively prime. Suppose that $K$ is an $H$-invariant subgroup of $F$. Then $|K : C_K(H)|$ divides $|F : C_F (H)|$.*

and near the end of the proof it says

"(...) Hence, the minimality of our counterexample implies that $F$ is a $p$-group for some prime $p$. The minimality of |$F$ : $K$| in our counterexample implies that $K$ is maximal among
the $H$-invariant subgroups of $F$. Let $\Phi$ be the Frattini subgroup of $F$. Since $K$ is
a proper subgroup, $K\Phi$ is a proper $H$-invariant subgroup of $F$, and it follows that
$\Phi \subseteq K$. Hence, $K$ is a normal subgroup of $F$."

I cannot see why the preceding deduction implies that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $F$.

First of all, I would like to say that the quoted part belongs to a larger proof, which does not appear here because I think that in the quoted part appears every hypothesis needed to proof the normality of $K$, but just in case I encorage you to read the whole proof (link below).

I have tried to get the result by proving that $K$ is a maximal subgroup of $F$, getting the normality due to the nilpotence of $F$, but this idea has not led me anywhere.

I also thought about using the H-invariant counterpart of the Sylow theorem's, but since $F$ is a $p$-group, it does not give me any information.

And finally, the property that if $F$ is a $p$-group, then $F/\Phi$ is elementary abelian, and since $\Phi \leq K$, $K/\Phi$ would also be, but once again, I doubt this helps solve the problem.

I would appreciate any help with this problem.

Thank you.

https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2004-132-09/S0002-9939-04-07412-X/S0002-9939-04-07412-X.pdf

Comment: You should at least add to your presentation that $H$ is a finite group acting on the finite group $F$ with $\vert H \vert$ and $\vert F \vert$ relatively prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $F/\Phi$ is (elementary) abelian, all of its subgroups are normal.  Therefore $K \Phi/ \Phi=K/ \Phi \lhd F/ \Phi$, which in turn implies that $K=K \Phi \lhd F$.